# prints blank space while using regex_extract method in pig

Tags: regex, apache-pig

I want to split the string for area conversion.I have the data like this.

```
(149Sq.Yards)
(151Sq.Yards)
(190Sq.Yards)
(190Sq.Yards)
```

I want to split the the above data like this.

```
149  sq.yards
151  sq.yards
```

i tried the following code.

```
a = LOAD '/user/ahmedabad/Makkan_PropertyDetails_Apartment_Ahmedabad.csv' using PigStorage('\t') as (SourceWebSite:chararray,PropertyID:chararray,ListedOn:chararray,ContactName:chararray,TotalViews:int,Price:chararray,PriceperArea:chararray,NoOfBedRooms:int,NoOfBathRooms:int,FloorNoOfProperty:chararray,TotalFloors:int,Possession:chararray,BuiltUpArea:chararray,Furnished:chararray,Ownership:chararray,NewResale:chararray,Facing:chararray,title:chararray,PropertyAddress:chararray,NearByFacilities:chararray,PropertyFeatures:chararray,Sellerinfo:chararray,Description:chararray);
b = FOREACH a GENERATE BuiltUpArea; 
c = FILTER b BY (BuiltUpArea matches '.*Sq.Yards.*');
d = FOREACH c GENERATE (bigdecimal) REGEX_EXTRACT(BuiltUpArea,'(.*)', 1) * 9;
```

while dump d .it prints as null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex that you mentioned will match all the characters, so it will try to multiply like this `(149Sq.Yards * 9)`. This is the reason for null in the output.

The below regex will split the numbers alone from the input and multiply like this `(149 * 9)`.

```
d = FOREACH c GENERATE (bigdecimal) REGEX_EXTRACT(BuiltUpArea,'(^[0-9]+)', 1) * 9;
dump d;
```